# UIButton jpg image?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I load a jpg image into the UIButton.
I want one image for when it is Not pressed.
And another image for when it is pressed.

thanks

(looking to do this programmatically... no interface builder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in interface builder there are properties and you can see that there are options for backgroundImage and Image for each state(normal,highlighted,selected,disabled) go to interface builder properties of UIButton you will find there. For images to appear in the combo box you need to add images to your project.

**UPDATE**

Code Snippet

```
        UIButton * btnShare=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
        [btnShare setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnShare setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxChecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [btnShare setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxChecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [btnShare addTarget: self  action: @selector(accessoryButtonTapped:withEvent:) 
           forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: you need to set images for highlighted and normal state

Answer (score 3):

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"not_pressed.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pressed.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

`not_pressed.jpg` and `pressed.jpg` are needed to be present in resource. Also you can use `setImage:forState:`. Please check [UIButton reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) for details of these methods.